# Save emojis to MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, emoji, unicode-string

I am trying to save emojis to my MYSQL database, I have followed these steps

3 STEPS

1. ALTER TABLE TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ALTER TABLE COLUMN modify Comment text charset utf8mb4;
2. SET NAMES utf8mb4;

From the above steps I am able save emojis to DB, but after some time I am not able to see those again, I have to execute the following command

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

Then it works

Is it nessary to use the following statement?

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

Can't we have a permanent fix or way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you have to execute the `SET NAMES` again sometimes, is that the command only modifies configuration for the current session.

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html):

> **13.7.5.3 SET NAMES Syntax**
>
> This statement sets the three session system variables character_set_client, character_set_connection, and character_set_results to the given character set.

If you want to permanently set it you need to set define it when the mysql service starts, or add it to your MySQL conf file.

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Alternatively (depending on which MySQL client you use for node) you might be able to define the connection character set directly from your client.